# How to create NSPredicate with array contains element

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I simply have `Address` entity with property `favourites` of type `[String]`

Address

```
@objc(Address)
class Address: NSManagedObject, Observer {
    @NSManaged var favourites: [String]
}
```

Suppose I have some addresses:

```
1: favourites: ["a", "b", "c"]
2: favourites: ["b", "c"]
3: favourites: ["a", "c"]
4: favourites: ["a"]
5: favourites: ["b"]
```

Now I need to fetch all addresses with `a` inside `favourites`. SO the result should be: `1, 3, 4`

In other words I need to check if `ANY element` in array `is equal` to specific string then object should be returned.

The following doesn't work:

```
NSPredicate(format: "favourites CONTAINS %@", "a")
```

This is how it is defined in `xcdatamodel`:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if (at least) one of the favorites is equal to the string "a"?

Comment: Are you asking for comparing one array in to another array?

Comment: If `favourites` is a transformable attribute, a predicate based on it will not work (at least not as part of a fetch request).

Comment: @MartinR yes ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot search in an array defined as transformable attribute with a predicate. Better define another entity

```
@objc(Favourite)
class Favourite: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

and a one-to-many relationship from "Address" to "Favourite".

The you can fetch all addresses which have any (i.e.: at least one) favorite equal to the string "a" with the predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY favourites.name == %@", "a")
```

or better with a compiler-checked key path literal:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K == %@", #keyPath(Address.favourites.name), "a")
```

For a case-insensitive comparison you can use

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K ==[c] %@", #keyPath(Address.favourites.name), "a")
```

Comment: Hello;) Thank you for your help, but it doesnt work;( Does it matter that I create NSPredicate for NSFRC?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: How does it not work? Do you get no results or wrong results?

Comment: If I assign `NSPredicate(value: true)` then I get all of them.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: I just saw your update: You *cannot* search in transformable attributes.

Comment: Ok, can I do it the other way? Is there a way to save array to core data and be able to search it?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: The usual way is to define a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Ok, so I should create another Entity with String only inside and used it as you said, right?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: Exactly. You define a "Favorite" entity with a "name" attribute, and then the predicate is `NSPredicate(format: "ANY favourites.name == %@", "a")`

Comment: So, I do it this way;) Thank you;)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [cheatsheet](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/), `CONTAINS` is for comparing *strings*. e.g. `"Hello" CONTAINS "e"`.

For *collections*, you should use `IN`:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN favourites", "a")
```

Comment: anyone checked if it works?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you cannot search in a transformable attribute.

An alternative to an extra entity is to save the string array joined with an unique separator as one string and declare a computed property to convert the string to array and vice versa

```
@NSManaged var favourites: String

private let uniqueSeparator = "®¥ð"

var favs : [String] {
    get { return favourites.components(separatedBy: uniqueSeparator) }
    set { favourites = newValue.joined(separator: uniqueSeparator)}
}
```

Then you can simply write

```
favs.contains("a")
```

Comment: But for a fetched results controller you would have to filter on the underlying string attribute directly.

Comment: @MartinR It depends. I'm using these kind of computed properties (adding KVO compliance) in fetch results controllers.