# Predicate an array for any value in array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, filter, nspredicate

I am using Core Data to make a fetch request. My object contains an array (transformable) and I want to predicate it for any value that this may contain that matches any value from another array.

```
let predicateCategories = NSPredicate(format: "ANY categories IN %@", categoriesA)
```

Where "categories" is the transfomable array and categoriesA is an array. I looking to predicate ANY value from categoriesA to ANY value from "categories".

I also tried Contains instead of IN but also no luck.

Any advise?

Comment: You cannot query the content of a transformable attribute, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/57658686/1187415.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create NSPredicate with array contains element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658686/how-to-create-nspredicate-with-array-contains-element)

Comment: @Willeke no.. i have already seen that. I want to predicate any value with in the array from any value within an array

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the answer but the link does not help me.. at the end I will filter after the fetch request

Comment: @Willeke please see my revised question

Comment: Consider to use `relationships` rather than transformable types.

Comment: Do you want to use the predicate in a fetch request or do you want to filter the result of the fetch?

Comment: @Willeke I prefer predicate

Comment: See [How to create NSPredicate with array contains element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57659038) "You cannot search in an array defined as transformable attribute with a predicate.".

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the reply thus the upvote. I ended up using a simple loop with contains(where: ...contains) . Did my task but I hoped i would find a way to predicate.